# Disable Winforms button while OnClick code executes in background

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I have some code in my "button_click" action. I want to disable the button during this code working.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        button1.IsEnabled = false;
        // some code (its take about 2-5 sec)
        button1.IsEnabled = true;
    }
```

But this doesn't work. The button never disables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run the "some code" part on a background thread:

```
button1.Enabled = false;
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    // some code (its take about 2-5 sec)
}).ContinueWith(task => {
    button1.Enabled = true;
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: Ok, now its working but i needed put there big block of Dispatcher code cause i generate there new components (like TreeView).

Comment: @Misha: you could try to separate the logic as much from the UI parts (and maybe delay creation if possible). In the end, there will be a lock up on the UI thread, but try to make it as less as possible.

Comment: @Misha right, I should have mentioned, any UI-related stuff has to be dispatched back to the UI thread.

Answer (score 2):

That is because your UI locks up during the entire action.

You should write the task in some sort of background thread.

You can use the `BackgroundWorker` for that, but better a `Task`.

```
BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
bgw.DoWork += bgw_DoWork;
bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += bgw_RunWorkerCompleted;

button.Enabled = false;

bgw.RunWorkerAsync();

private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   // your task
}

private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // update the button
    button.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: What's the need of queuing it on dispatcher? `RunWorkerCompleted` is called on UI thread only.

Answer (score 1):

`Dispatcher` is responsible for message pumping in WPF. Every thread has dispatcher associated with it which is responsible for queuing stuffs on that thread based on `DispatcherPriority` of items.

In your case GUI rendering is done on `DispatcherPriority.Render` but right now dispatcher is busy executing your button click event handler code so GUI rendering never happens until it finishes with your code execution. That's why you see button to be refreshed only when your handler gets executed completely.

On a sidenote what [McGarnagle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21586337/632337) proposed gonna work but you can do it other way round as well by explicitly queuing empty delegate on dispatcher with priority `Render` which will force all queued items with priority higher or equal to Render to be processed before proceeding further. Hence, you will see refresh on your GUI:

```
button1.IsEnabled = false;
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => { }),
                                       DispatcherPriority.Render);
// some code (its take about 2-5 sec)
button1.IsEnabled = true;
```